# Using the same HashMapM<String,....> for String and array of String (String[])

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have some attributes that are of the type String, and the type "ArrayString" (String[]). How can I put then in the same HashMap?

Example:

```
String data;
String[] array;
... // Initialize and put the values in attributes
HashMap <String, *> hm = new HashMap<String, *> // * -> it's what i want
hm.put ("data", data);
hm.put("array", array);
```

Which value, or class, must be in *?

Comment: That wouldn't be type-safe.

Comment: So... I can't do it?

Comment: No.  Wrap the strings in arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd go about it a different way - always store the values as `String[]`, and if you have a single value just store it in an array with a single element). It would make your code considerably simpler.

If you absolutely must mix `String`s and `String[]`s, you can only use `Object` as the value type (i.e., `HashMap<String, Object>`, and will have to use runtime type identification in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 HashMap<String, List<String>>
```

instead to accomplish your goals. If this doesn't suit you please provide more context and I'd be glad to help